# SQL query condition to select specific records on a particular table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have three tables

```
Users ( ID - Name )
Services (ID - Name)
UserServices ( ID - USerID- ServiceID )
```

I want to select serviceName that not belong to user

eg :
if i have three users and 10 services

First user belong to 3 services so i want to select other 7 services only

Comment: @KiNeTiC No, _eg_ (exempli gratia) means _for example_ in latin; it's commonly used in Enlish too.

Comment: I didn't know that.  English is not my primary language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT S.ID, S.Name
FROM Services AS S 
LEFT JOIN UserServices AS US
ON US.ServiceID = S.ID
AND US.UserID = @UserID
WHERE US.ServiceID IS NULL
```

So, select the services where there are no matching UserServices for that User Id. I also changed your US.ID to US.UserID, change it back if US.ID actually does contain your UserIDs.

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to get the results you want, this is one :

```
SELECT S.ID, S.Name
FROM  UserServices AS US
INNER JOIN Services AS S ON US.ServiceID = S.ID
WHERE US.UserID <> @UserID
```

Comment: So if i want to select services based on UserID ?? i mean first user has 3 services so i want to select other services for this user, this need to define relation between users and UserServices

Comment: The <> is a problem. If there are 10 Users and you run this for 1 of them you will get all the records for the other 9 users.